# Cauchy's Mean-Value Theorem for three or more functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Cauchy's mean-value theorem is itself a generalization of the "normal" mean value theorem. My question is, does this generalization go one? If there are three functions $f,g,h: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, which are differentiable on (a,b) and continuous on [a,b]. Also $g'(x)\neq 0 \; \forall x \in (a,b)$. Is then true? $$\implies \exists \xi \in (a,b):\quad \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)} \cdot \frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)} \cdot h'(\xi)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=x$$
the conditions are satisfied

we will get $$h(\xi)=\xi=1$$

Comment: Sorry, I asked my question wrong and had to edit it. Your example works. My question still is, does such a $\xi$ always exist?

Comment: @FabioN Try with $ f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=x^2$